# SharePoint subsites and infoPath forms

Tags: list, sharepoint, infopath

I'm new with Sharepoint so I' m sorry if I'm not very clear.

I created a form with InfoPath for the main site (Ex. http://mysharepointsite.com/) that works well and save this app as a template (Ex. Test InfoPath form) to be able to use it in a subsite.

Then, when I created my new subsite (Ex. http://mysharepointsite.com/test/) and add my "Test InfoPath form" app, it's works. But when I click on "new item/new document", the following error appears.

The error appears in read AND edit view.
[image: Error message when I click on "new item"]

Then, I click "OK" and my form appears correctly but none of the Lookups are working.

My account is an admin/full control account so I don't understand why this should be permissions issue.

Comment: Is your form using any list or assets from the root site?